# Magento2 : Apple Pay Integration With Payfort Payment

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, payment-methods

I have to integrate the apple pay payment method to my website so anyone have any reference URL or Extension. so I can use that link.

**I follow below link**

- https://applepaydemo.apple.com/
- https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/payment-platforms/
- https://github.com/norfolkmustard/ApplePayJS

Comment: Can you check if this free extension is usable - https://github.com/tiamo/magento2-applepay

Comment: Have you integrated Apple pay?

Comment: hi @kushal Dani have you implemented this plz let me know

Comment: Currently, I have not implemented the functionality

Comment: thanks for reply you have any idea how can start?

Comment: how the finger print option will show can you share some knowledge what we need before starting deails from client?

Comment: have you done? i still not success with payfort

Comment: @kusha Dani ? you done?

Comment: https://www.aalogics.com/apple-pay-with-payfort-payment-for-magento-2-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found one paid extension that can help to solve this problem

https://www.aalogics.com/apple-pay-with-payfort-payment-for-magento-2-extension

Comment: Thanks, this extension worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

I need to ask you,
I have used this extension
https://www.aalogics.com/apple-pay-with-payfort-payment-for-magento-2-extension

how it works with you, I have an error when I use it, can you help me?

Comment: you can communicate in support. https://www.aalogics.com/productssupport-policy

Comment: thank you aalogics very much, the issue was resolved by the support team and everything is up and running, this was only a certificate issue and it is resolved now, thank you.