# Apple Pay Payfort Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I want to implement payfort apple pay in magento2 how I achieve this?

Comment: Have you create a developer account for taht?

Comment: yes created on developer.apple.com

Comment: This user https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276677/magento2-apple-pay-integration-with-payfort-payment also want to integrate Apple pay co-ordinate with him it might be a chance to get some information.