# Apple Pay Integration With Payfort in Magento2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, integration

I am a newbie to Magento. 
I have to integrate the apple pay with payfort payment method to my magento website. So anyone has any reference URL or any idea about this? 
Please give a reply.

Comment: Please use https://github.com/tiamo/magento2-applepay free module

Comment: @rakesh. Thanks for your reply. I have already checked this above module, which you sent. But I have to integrate with Payfort. This free module is through the Braintree payment gateway. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276677/magento2-apple-pay-integration-with-payfort-payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one paid extension so that can help to solve this problem

https://www.aalogics.com/apple-pay-with-payfort-payment-for-magento-2-extension